# Is it possible to serve the same root from autoindex both as JSON and HTML with nginx?

Tags: nginx

With nginx I'd like to be able to serve the same location both as JSON and as HTML

So the path `/files/` could serve `/srv/www/files/` with autoindex as HTML and
`/api/` would serve the listing of `/srv/www/files/` as JSON.

Is that possible?

I've been trying with rewrite and different locations but failed.

Answer (score 2):

Use `root` or `alias` within the `location` block to specify the path to the files. Use `alias` when the path cannot be calculated using simple concatenation of the document root with the URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

For example:

```
root /srv/www;

location /files/ { 
    autoindex on; 
}

location /api/ { 
    autoindex on; 
    autoindex_format json; 
    alias /srv/www/files/;
}
```